# 'Save Palette' button gives a TypeError of 'savePalette' is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

My 'NewPaletteForm' is a **functional component** as I've used **react hooks**.

So when I click the button 'Save Palette', an error occurs which says '**props.savePalette is not a function**'.

**ERROR:-**
TypeError: props.savePalette is not a function

**Code:**

**'App.js':**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { palettes: seedColors };
    this.findPalette = this.findPalette.bind(this);
    this.savePalette = this.savePalette.bind(this);
  }
  findPalette(id) {
    return this.state.palettes.find(function (palette) {
      return palette.id === id;
    });
  }

  savePalette(newPalette) {
    this.setState({ palettes: [...this.state.palettes, newPalette] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path='/palette/new'
          render={(routeProps) => <NewPaletteForm savePalette={this.savePalette} {...routeProps} />} />
```

**'NewPaletteForm.js' :** Functional Component which includes react hooks

```
function NewPaletteForm() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState('teal');
    const [colors, setColors] = useState([{ color: 'pink', name: 'pink' }]);
    const [newName, setNewName] = useState('');

    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        ValidatorForm.addValidationRule('isColorNameUnique', (value) => {
             
            return colors.every(
                ({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() !== value.toLowerCase()
            );
        });

        
        ValidatorForm.addValidationRule('isColorUnique', (value) => {
            
            return colors.every(
                ({ color }) => color !== currentColor
            );
        });
    })
    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    function updateCurrentColor(newColor) {
        setCurrentColor(newColor.hex);
    };

    function addNewColor() {
        const newColor = {
            color: currentColor,
            name: newName
        }
        setColors(oldColors => [...oldColors, newColor]);
      
        setNewName('');
    };

    function handleChange(evt) {
        setNewName(evt.target.value);
    }

    function handleSubmit(props) {
        const newPalette = {
            paletteName: 'Test Palette',
            colors: colors
        }
        
        props.savePalette(newPalette);
        
        props.history.push('/');
    }
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar
                position="fixed"
                color='default'
                className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
                    [classes.appBarShift]: open,
                })}
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="open drawer"
                        onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                        edge="start"
                        className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                        Persistent drawer
                    </Typography>
                    <Button variant='contained' color='primary' onClick={handleSubmit}>Save Palette</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                variant="persistent"
                anchor="left"
                open={open}
                classes={{
                    paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                }}
            >
                <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                    <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                        <ChevronLeftIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
                <Typography variant='h4'>Design Your Palette</Typography>
                <div>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
                        Clear Palette
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                        Random Color
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <Divider />
                <ChromePicker color={currentColor} onChangeComplete={updateCurrentColor} />
                <ValidatorForm onSubmit={addNewColor}>
                    <TextValidator
                        value={newName}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        validators={['required', 'isColorNameUnique', 'isColorUnique']}
                        errorMessages={['Enter a color name', 'Color name must be unique', 'Color already used!']}
                    />
                    <Button
                        variant='contained'
                        type='submit'
                        color='primary'
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: currentColor
                        }}
                    >
                        Add Color
                    </Button>
                </ValidatorForm>

            </Drawer>
            <main
                className={clsx(classes.content, {
                    [classes.contentShift]: open,
                })}
            >
                <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
                {colors.map(color => (
                    <DraggableColorBox color={color.color} name={color.name} />
                ))}
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Button in the NewPaletteForm Component:** (Used Material UI Button component)

```
            <Button variant='contained' color='primary' onClick={handleSubmit}>Save Palette</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `props` from function argument. because you are calling `handleSubmit` on button click so it's getting `event` as `props`.

```
function handleSubmit() {
        const newPalette = {
            paletteName: 'Test Palette',
            color: colors
        }
        props.savePalette(newPalette);
        props.history.push('/');
}
```

Also add `props` argument to `function NewPaletteForm(props) {`

Comment: But if I remove props, then it says 'props is not defined'... I get a compiler error.

Comment: post your `NewPaletteForm.js` component code so  that i can suggest you

Comment: if it is class based component you can use `this.props.savePalette(newPalette);`

Comment: I've added the complete NewPaletteForm.js component. It is a functional component which uses react hooks.

Comment: updated ans, add `props` to `function NewPaletteForm(props)`

Comment: @AshmitaSingh are you able to fix it ?